# Is there a Python idiom for evaluating a list of functions/expressions with short-circuiting?

Tags: functional-programming, python, list-comprehension, short-circuiting

I wrote a simple script to solve a "logic puzzle", the type of puzzle from school where you are given a number of rules and then must be able to find the solution for problems like "There are five musicians named A, B, C, D, and E playing in a concert, each plays one after the other... if A goes before B, and D is not last ... what is the order of who plays when?" etc.

To evaluate possible solutions, I wrote each "rule" as a separate function which would evaluate if a possible solution (represented simply as a list of strings) is valid, for example

```
#Fifth slot must be B or D
def rule1(solution):
    return solution[4] == 'B' or solution[4] == 'D'

#There must be at least two spots between A and B
def rule2(solution):
    returns abs(solution.index('A') - solution.index('B')) >= 2

#etc...
```

I'm interested in finding the Pythonic way to test if a possible solution passes all such rules, with the ability to stop evaluating rules after the first has failed.

At first I wrote the simplest possible thing:

```
def is_valid(solution):
    return rule1(solution) and rule2(solution) and rule3(solution) and ...
```

But this seemed rather ugly. I thought perhaps I could make this read a bit more elegant with something like a list comprehension...

```
def is_valid(solution)
    rules = [rule1, rule2, rule3, rule4, ... ]
    return all([r(solution) for f in rules])
```

... but then I realized that since the list comprehension is generated before the `all()` function is evaluated, that this has the side effect of not being short-circuited at all - every rule will be evaluated even if the first returns `False`.

So my question is: is there a more Pythonic/functional way to be able to evaluate a list of `True`/`False` expressions, with short-circuiting, without the need to write out a long list of `return f1(s) and f2(s) and f3(s) ...` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
rules = [ rule1, rule2, rule3, rule4, ... ]
rules_generator = ( r( solution ) for r in rules )
return all( rules_generator )
```

Syntactic sugar: you can omit the extra parentheses:

```
rules = [ rule1, rule2, rule3, rule4, ... ]
return all( r( solution ) for r in rules )
```

A generator is (basically) an object with a `.next()` method, which returns the next item in some iterable. This means they can do useful things like read a file in chunks without loading it all into memory, or iterate up to huge integers. You can iterate over them with `for` loops transparently; Python handles it behind-the-scenes. For instance, `range` is a generator in Py3k.

You can roll your own custom generator expressions by using the `yield` statement instead of `return` in a function definition:

```
def integers():
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield i
```

and Python will handle saving the function's state and so on. They're awesome!

Comment: So is the basic difference here omitting the brackets in `return all([r(solution) for r in rules])`, thus not creating a list of all results before `all()` is evaluated?

Comment: Yes. In both cases the argument to `all` is evaluated before being passed on, but evaluating a list comprehension creates the entire list in memory whereas evaluating a generator expression creates a generator object, which loads the elements on demand.

Comment: I was looking for similar -- but I wanted a short circuit as soon as anything was `True` instead of `False`. I changed `all()` to `any()` and it worked.