# How do I ensure a list of arbitrary function calls is not eagerly evaluated past the short circuit point while processing in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, yield, short-circuiting

For example, given

```
def expensive_call(x):
    print(x)
    if x == "d":
        return x
def expensive_call_2(x, y):
    print(x)
    print(y)
    return x + y

a = [expensive_call("a"), expensive_call_2("b", "c"), expensive_call("d")]
next((e for e in a if e is not None), 'All are Nones')
```

the output is

```
a
b
c
d
Out[22]: 'bc'
```

Since `expensive_call("d")` is eagerly evaluated, note that "d" is printed even though the `next` call short-circuits at the second call with an output of "bc".

I am hard coding the calls in the list `a`, and `a` doesn't have to be a list data structure.

One potential solution is as follows:

```
a = ['expensive_call("a")', 'expensive_call_2("b", "c")', 'expensive_call("d")']
def generator():
    for e in a:
        r = eval(e)
        if r is not None:
            yield r
next(generator(), 'All are Nones')
```

the output is

```
a
b
c
Out[23]: 'bc'
```

as desired. However, I don't really like having to use eval. I would also prefer not to use any solution that initially keeps the function pointer and the arguments separate like `(expensive_call, ("a"))`. Ideally I would have something like

```
a = lazy_magic([expensive_call("a"), expensive_call_2("b", "c"), expensive_call("d")])
next((e for e in a if e is not None), 'All are Nones')
```

Note that https://stackoverflow.com/a/3405828/2750819 is a similar question but only applies for when the functions have the same method signature.

Comment: This doesn't seem possible without separating the method calls and the arguments, because in order to evaluate `[expensive_call("a")...]` as you have in your example, all the calls need to be evaluated. Even if you used a generator comprehension, the comprehension would have to be of the form `((expensive_call("a"), expensive_call_2("b", "c"), expensive_call("d")) for _ in range(1))` since you don't know your exact specifications, and thus is unusable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could put them all in a function and yield the results:

```
def gen():
    yield expensive_call("a")
    yield expensive_call_2("b", "c")
    yield expensive_call("d")


result = next(
    (value for value in gen() if value is not None),
    'All are Nones')
```

Another solution is to use [**`partial`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) application:

```
from functools import partial

calls = [partial(expensive_call, 'a'),
         partial(expensive_call_2, 'b', 'c'),
         partial(expensive_call, 'd')]
```

Then evaluate:

```
next((result for call in calls
      for result in [call()]
      if result is not None),
     'All results None')
```

Comment: A bit cruder than I imagined but squinting enough by replacing yield with a comma and this is basically as if I was writing a list structure. I'll use this, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand "crude" and "squinting".

Comment: Well I like this because I can use regex on my existing list and basically convert every comma into a yield. And then delete the existing "[" and "]", add the first "yield", and then add the function definition. In like 15 seconds of manipulations, I now have a "lazy list". And so if I "squint", the whole structure just looks like a plain list with one element on each line.

Comment: I say "crude" because it has this brute-force quality. Maybe "simple" is a better word.

Comment: I added an example using [**`partial`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

Comment: @PeterWood I think OP said he didn't want to split function and argument, but good solution. +1

Comment: @rassar I interpreted it that they didn't want to manage splitting and recombining themselves.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following decorator:

```
def lazy_fn(fn):
    return lambda *args: lambda: fn(*args)
```

(Also expressible as `lazy_fn = lambda fn: lambda *args: lambda: fn(*args)`
 if you like lambdas.)

Use it like this:

```
@lazy_fn
def expensive_call(x):
    print(x)
    if x == "d":
        return x

@lazy_fn
def expensive_call_2(x, y):
    print(x)
    print(y)
    return x + y

a = [expensive_call("a"), expensive_call_2("b", "c"), expensive_call("d")]
print(next((e for e in map(lambda i: i(), a) if e is not None), 'All are Nones'))
```

Outputs:

```
a
b
c
bc
```

Note that instead of using `for e in a`, you need to use `for e in map(lambda i: i(), a)`.

Comment: Interesting. I had not thought of this but adding @lazy_fn to every function in that list doesn't quite keep the simplicity I want. Thanks for the suggestion anyways.

Comment: [**`partial`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) does this job already.